# assertEquals fails on two Vectors

Tags: java

I want to write accelerate method for `Ship` class so I have written

```
public void accelerate(double fo){
    double newSpeedMag = speed.magnitude() + fo;
    speed = new Vector(Math.cos(facing) * newSpeedMag , Math.sin(facing) * newSpeedMag  );
}
```

Where `facing` is facing angle and currently `facing == Math.PI`.

In `testAccelerate()` test case:

```
testAccelerate(){
    s.facing = Math.PI/2;
    s.accelerate(4);
    assertEquals("wrong vector",new Vector(-3,4),s.speed);
}
```

`assertEquals` is failing.

Comment: Your physics is odd. Just decompose position, velocity and acceleration into x and y and handle them independently for a correct physics simulation. Magnitude doesn't enter into it (until you get to speed-variable friction)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is the implementation of your `Vector` class?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you most likely did not override equals for your class. Without this, there is no way for assertEquals to know if the classes are equal (well it tries, but will only return true if the point to the same memory address).

See this link for overriding equals on your class - http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~kmammen/documents/java/howToOverrideEquals.html.